# How to trigger amcharts Map from ouside link

Tags: dictionary, triggers, amcharts

I want to trigger the map info window from an outside link. For example, we add country link on the map sidebar and want to open the info window from the country list link.

http://projects.thesparxitsolutions.com/SIS415/business-world-map

Answer (score 0):

You can open multiple **description windows** setting `allowMultipleDescriptionWindows` to **true** in your config and then calling `clickMapObject` on the desired areas to open them programmatically, for example:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("mapdiv", {
  // ...
  allowMultipleDescriptionWindows: true, 
  listeners: [
    {
      event: "rendered",
      method: function(e) {
        var map = e.chart;
        //trigger the description windows for these regions
        map.clickMapObject(map.getObjectById("FR-D"));
        map.clickMapObject(map.getObjectById("FR-E"));
      }
    }
  ]
});
```